# What is the phenomenon called, when things start resembling what you are thinking about?

Tags: word-usage

like when Tom is hungry he sees jerry as a hot dog. When you are searching for something every other thing appears that it is the very thing you are searching for.

EDIT:

So as suggested in the comment here is what I want exactly:

I want to give title to this event which happened: On 31st December as I looked into an old message which my friend had sent me, I got surprised as to when he sent me a Happy New Year message, when suddenly I realized that it was written "Happy to Hear"

Comment: It's a perceptual bias; arguably, it's a confirmation bias.

Comment: When and how will you use this word? Can you show us an example sentence? The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You just seem to have *misread* the text!  What you have described with Tom & Jerry and in your EDIT are two different things entirely.

Comment: antipsychotic medication compliance. haha, I'm kidding. Sometimes I slip into lucidity naturally after eating fava beans.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I thought the original text and the EDIT match, on 31st Dec when there is a hype of new year everywhere you tend to read "Happy to Hear" as the new year message, in other normal days you have least chances of making this mistake

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a psychologist or a psychiatrist, but this sounds like it fits the term [perceptual distortion](http://www.wiley.com/college/schermerhorn/047120367X/ppt/ch05.ppt), particularly the variant termed *self-fulfilling prophesy* on slide 21 in the link.

From [montofacto.com](http://www.mondofacto.com/facts/dictionary?perceptual%20distortion):

> Perceptual distortion: Lack of correspondence between the way a stimulus is commonly perceived and the way an individual perceives it under given conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **mirage**. [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mirage)

> an optical effect that is sometimes seen at sea, in the desert, or over a hot pavement, that may have the appearance of a pool of water or a mirror in which distant objects are seen inverted

Comment: but mirage is also observed by a person who is not thirsty, I want to know the concept which is only observed by a thirsty person for example.

Comment: If it is not `mirage`, I think the next best word I can think of is, `phantasm` which also happens to be a synonym of `mirage`.

Comment: `Phantasm` is defined as:

>a figment of the imagination; an illusion or apparition

Comment: Isn't that what I just did?

Comment: I just tried to guide you. Hope you didn't take it personally. And you need to put @ before a display name like @rathony to ping them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perceptual projection and attribution (or misattribution)